# Quickblox - iOS - Content - get url blobID

Tags: ios, quickblox

we have being able to get content files by blob_id with your code:

```
[QBContent TDownloadFileWithBlobID:126  delegate:self];

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBActionStatusDelegate

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBCFileDownloadTaskResult class]]){
        QBCFileDownloadTaskResult *downloadfileResult = (QBCFileDownloadTaskResult *)result;

        // do something with file
        NSData file = downloadfileResult.file;
    }else{
        NSLog("errors=%@", result.errors);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the image URL using the blob_id

thanks for your help

Comment: QBCFileDownloadTaskResult *res = (QBCFileDownloadTaskResult *)result;
  NSLog(@"[res.blob publicUrl] %@",[res.blob publicUrl]) ; but u should upload the file with public flag set to YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example

```
[QBContent blobWithID:910 delegate:self];

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{

    // success result
    if(result.success){
        if([result isKindOfClass:QBCBlobResult.class]){
            QBCBlobResult *res = (QBCBlobResult *)result;
            NSLog(@"url=%@", res.blob.publicUrl); 
        }
    }
}
```

But, to be able to do this you should upload a file and set **isPublic** to YES

If file is private - you can't use a **publicUrl** property